# How does Woot.com's email share button increment?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, email

How does Woot increment their email button? It opened in my Mail app (mac) and after I sent the email to a friend the count went up. I thought it was just counting clicks, but it's not. Has anyone ever seen something similar to this before?

[image]

Comment: What e-mail button?  Screenshot?  URL?

Comment: Maybe they count the emails they recieve? You wrote you send an email.

Comment: @harke, I sent an email to a friend (added that in my description)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like clicking triggers a JavaScript function `trackEvent()` that sends something like this:

```
eventType   click
linkType    Email
objectId    457a6f32-4e00-4265-b8fb-09175a41a5ec
```

to Woot's servers which causes the counter to increment. It doesn't update the count without a page refresh which may make it look like the action is more delayed than it actually is, which may be why you thought it was tracking actual emails rather than clicks. I looked in the email it generates and there's nothing dynamic in it that could be tracked or cause an increment.

URL + params:
http://www.woot.com/analytics/trackevent?eventType=click&linkType=Email&objectId=457a6f32-4e00-4265-b8fb-09175a41a5ec

Answer (score 1):

Look at the onclick...  `trackEvent()`...

If not that one, some other JS that gets fired off.  In any case, they aren't actually tracking your e-mail.  they're just tracking what gets clicked.